# Displaying Elements from a Get Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am currently trying to learn React, and am trying to solve a challenge exercise. I have a simple JSON array stored on a port (Node), to which I use the fetch API to call it into my react server. The request seems to go through, but I am unable to display any of the elements of the JSON objects onto my react page.

I've tried researching the problem, but nothing seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

This is the main App page, which makes the get request to the Node server hosted on port 5555 (/list) which contains JSON elements.

```
class App extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              cartList: []
            };
         }
        componentDidMount(){
  fetch("http://localhost:5555/list").then(data => 
       data.json()).then(data => this.setState({cartList: 
       data})).catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
         render() {
            return (
              <div className="Cart-App">
                  <header className="App-header">
                      <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Shopping- 
                      R-US!</h1>
                      <Cart cartList = {this.state.cartList}/>
                  </header>
              </div>
          );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

And this is the class where I am attempting to display the elements, where I use the map function to go through the array, and display the specific attributes from the JSON objects that I want.

```
class Cart extends Component {
     render() {
         const products = this.props.cartList.map(product => (
             <div className = "col-md-4">
                 <p>
                    {product.name}
                    {product.description}
                    {product.cost}
                 </p>
             </div>    
         ))             
         return (
              <div className = "products">     
                 <header className="Cart-Header">
                   <h1 className="App-title">Select which items you want from the catalog below!</h1>
                  </header>
                  <p className="Cart-Products">
                       {products}  
                   </p>
               </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default Cart;
```

The goal here is to just display the elements of the array (or at least specific attributes) onto the page under the header.

Comment: what is inside `data` in your fetch? maybe you need data.json() before access the real data

Comment: `console.log(data)` in the fetch call and see if you are getting data in pure JSON form.